# Python: Choosing specific line from row with button

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a program which is to be used by a company in order to manage their orders.
The program is mostly done, however, I am stuck on a specific part.

[Tkinter UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6nOi.png)

The image shows the Tkinter UI, which is based upon an entry box that is used to search the database for an order like the name entered. The "Oppdater" button is not relevant, and the search button is used to display the results of the query.

In this case I searched for the name Lars, which provides three entries(names hidden).
What I would like to do is use the "Velg"(Choose) button in order to select the data from that specific order, however when I try to select that data all it does is print the last order, with number 100.

How can I fix this code to be able to select the specific row and save the data to a variable?(Or pass it to a function)

```
print("Searching using a name")
search_query = "SELECT * FROM {} WHERE name LIKE '%{}".format(orders_table, self.search_entry.get()) + "%'"
mycursor.execute(search_query, )
data = mycursor.fetchall()
for count, element in enumerate(data, 1):
    print(count, element)
    tk.Label(self.info_frame, text="Ordr.number: {}".format(element[0]), font=medium_font).grid(column=0, sticky=W, row="{}".format(count))
    ttk.Button(self.info_frame, text="Choose", command="").grid(column=1, sticky=W, row="{}".format(count))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this as an answer because its not understandable by comments. Instead of complicating the query, why dont you try:

```
value = self.search_entry.get()
search_query = "SELECT * FROM {} WHERE name LIKE %s".format(orders_table)
mycursor.execute(search_query, (value,))
data = mycursor.fetchall()

ref = []
for count,element in enumerate(data):
    def show(item):
        print(item)
    Label(root, text=f"Ordr.number: {element[0]}").grid(column=0, sticky=W, row=count)
    ref.append(Button(root, text="Choose", command=lambda item=element: show(item)))
    ref[count].grid(column=1, sticky=W, row=count)
```

I did not use `format` method instead i used f strings, which are much easier to use with less number of codes in python 3.x

Anyway try this out and let me know. Make sure to let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: Thank you, yeah using f strings is a bit easier to use, I can see that!
Made some slight changes to the query with the inputs you added aswell, which makes the code a  bit cleaner.

However, the issue lies more with how to access the data using the button, do you have any inputs on how to solve that?

Thank you

Comment: @Helfie I dont see any command specified to the `command` argument. Why is that?

Comment: What I am struggling to understand is how to select the specific rows with the button.
I.e in the image, choose order number 51 and print the contents of it by using the button on that line. Sorry if its a bit unclear. Nothing is specified in the command because thats the part i dont understand. How to specify the specific line.

Comment: @Helfie Its actually unclear, but what do you want to print? when the button is pressed?

Comment: In the image there are three lines, as per the three results on the order.
I want to be able to click the button generated by the for loop to select a line.
I.e if I press the button on the 2nd line, i select the order with the number 51.

A test command would just be to put print(count, element) on that row, however that just prints the last one, number 100.

Sorry for the unclarity!

Comment: @Helfie That is because the loop is completed. So last value is 100, Could you tell me exactly what you want to print only and also include an example of what `print(data)` looks like.

Comment: I want to the button on lets say row 2, which has the order number 51 to print the data associated with that row. When any of the buttons now are clicked, it prints the data associated with the bottom row, which as you said is because the loop is finished. 
I just dont understand how to access that data.

Comment: @Helfie I guess there is a way if there is something connecting those buttons and the records? like the order number? Could you include the `print(data)` so its more clear on what is happening .

Comment: print(data) shows a list of in this case three orders. Starting with the one with order 16, and then 51, and then 100. Not posting it here as it is too long with a lot of data. 16, 51, 100 is the order numbers which can be used to identify them.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I cant seem to find a way to connect the button to the specific line, for example how the label shows the order  number and is connected to it but the button is not. Which is something I dont understand.

Comment: That worked!
Thank you very much, I had no idea that it could be done like that.